# Delphi DrawGrid only displays first image

Tags: delphi

I want to display a list of images in a `TDrawGrid`.  In the example below, my DrawGrid only displays 1 image and its the first image.  The other 2 images do not display in the grid.  The grid's `RowCount` is 3 and the `ColCount` is 1.

```
procedure DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  JImg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  JImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;

  try
    JImg.LoadFromFile('c:\tmp\photo'+IntToStr(ARow+1)+'.jpeg');

    Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    Bmp.Width := 73;
    Bmp.Height := 73;

    R.Top := Rect.Top + 1;
    R.Left := Rect.Left + 1;
    R.Right := R.Left + 73;
    R.Bottom := R.Top + 73;
    Bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, JImg);
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, Bmp);
  finally
    JImg.Free;
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are drawing the `TJPEGImage` onto the `TBitmap` using the wrong `TRect` values.  The values you are using are relative to the Grid, not to the `TBitmap`, so the 2nd and subsequent images are being drawn outside of the `TBitmap`'s bounds.

You need to use something more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  ARect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  JImg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  JImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    JImg.LoadFromFile(Format('c:\tmp\photo%d.jpeg', [ARow+1]));

    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      Bmp.Width := 73;
      Bmp.Height := 73;

      R := Rect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
      Bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, JImg);

      R.Offset(ARect.Left, ARect.Top);
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, Bmp);
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    JImg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, there is actually no need for the `TBitmap` at all, as you can draw the `TJPEGImage` directly onto the grid's `Canvas` instead:

```pascal
procedure DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  ARect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  R: TRect;
  JImg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  JImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    JImg.LoadFromFile(Format('c:\tmp\photo%d.jpeg', [ARow+1]));

    R := Rect(0, 0, 73, 73);
    R.Offset(ARect.Left + 1, ARect.Top + 1);
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, JImg);
  finally
    JImg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, this code is re-loading the `.jpeg` files every time the grid is re-painted onscreen.  You should load the files one time and cache the images, such as in a `TImageList`.  Or, simply don't use `TDrawGrid` at all.  For instance, you can place a series of `TImage` controls on a `TScrollBox`, and then load the `.jpeg` files into the `TImage` controls, letting them handle drawing for you.

Comment: I get an error on the line R := Rect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);  {Missing operator or semicolon}  The reason I used the BMP is to resize the Jpeg.  Also I cannot use an Image list since my images are dynamic and created by a webcam. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: "you can place a series of TImage controls on a TScrollBox, and then load the .jpeg files into the TImage controls, letting them handle drawing for you."  This is what I originally tried but was not successful.. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Lou "*I get an error*" - did you rename the `Rect` parameter, like I showed in my example? `Rect()` is a function, but it is also a parameter name in your original code. Avoid the name conflict. "*The reason I used the BMP is to resize the Jpeg*" - all you are doing is stretching the JPG onto the BMP and then drawing the BMP as-is. So just stretch the JPG onto the Grid instead. Same effect, less overhead. "*I cannot use an Image list since my images are dynamic*" - You can update the ImageList when you have new JPGs. "*This is what I originally tried but was not successful*" - Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
R.Top := Rect.Top + 1;
....
Bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, JImg);
```

This code draws jpeg in shifted region of bitmap, so you cannot see it.

Define rectangle in bitmap active region. Possible way:

```
  R.Top := 0;
  R.Left := 0;
  R.Right := 73;
  R.Bottom := 73;

  Bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, JImg);
  OffsetRect(R, Rect.Left + 1, Rect.Top + 1);
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.StretchDraw(R, Bmp);
```